# checkbox - Want to select a particular record for editing by selecting a checkbox. ID is dynamic so need someidea to search by Name

Tags: ruby, selenium

Want to select a particular record for editing by selecting a checkbox. ID is dynamic so need some idea to search by Name.need the Xpath.

suppose there are 20 records in a record list with checkbox in front of them.
Of the 20 records I want to click on the checkbox containg the name 'Janine'.How can I proceed with this, plz provide some idea.

I could have used @id = rowselect12 as an Xpath but since the ID is dynamic with my application.so this  did not help.

for link the Xpath =  //a[contains(text(),'Janine')] works well but for checkbox this does not work.
Please let me know how to select the particulat checkbox via Name (Xpath)

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to select a checkbox by 'value', myself. Doing that Cucumber thang.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is like:

```
<html>
       <input type=checkbox>
       <a>Janine</a>
</html>
```

You can use the following XPATH to select the checkbox for near to Janine

```
xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Janine')]/preceding-sibiling::input
```

If your checkbox comes after the anchor element like:

```
<html>
    <a>Janine</a>
    <input type=checkbox>   
</html>
```

you can use

```
xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Janine')]/following-sibling::input
```

You can learn more about these [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

//td[.='Janine']/../td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']

This will work in your case...I too faced similar issue but the above xpath solved my issue.

KR,
Navin Sharma